# How can i parse this array

Tags: php

Lets say this was my retrieved object `$myObj`

```
Array
(
    [0] => xl_oio_0_1_Mytitle Object
                (
                        [_unknown:protected] => 
                        [header_:protected] => Header Object
                                (
                                        [_unknown:protected] => 
                                        [myId_:protected] => my_title
                                        [userId_:protected] => 
                                        [createTime_:protected] => 
                                )

                        [id_:protected] => ID Object
                                (
                                        [_unknown:protected] => 
                                        [id_:protected] => ingy3spdzE1uiMtCYRSlmwtX
                                )

                        [dataType_:protected] => 2
                        [picSize_:protected] => 8669
                        [userId_:protected] => ID Object
                                (
                                        [_unknown:protected] => 
                                        [id_:protected] => ingy3spdzE1uiMtCYRSlmwtX
                                )

                        [fName_:protected] => Joe
                        [lName_:protected] => Smith
                        [cDate_:protected] => RxyascTe89Xe4
                )
    [1] => etc...
```

And I am trying to parse the name and date, ive tried the following with no luck.

```
$i=0;
while( $i < 20 ){

    // Notice: Trying to get property of non-object
    //$firstName    = $myObj->xl_oio_0_1_Mytitle->fName_;

    // Fatal error: Cannot use object of type
    //$firstName    = $myObj[$i]['fName_'];

    // Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_OBJECT_OPERATOR
    $firstName  = $myObj->xl_oio_0_1_Mytitle(object->fName_);
    echo $firstName . '<br />';
    $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is simple: You cannot access any of these values unless the object provides getter methods for them.

Try `$myObj[$i]->getFName()` - that's the most likely name to get the `fName` property.

If you do not like trial and error either look at the code of the object or use Reflection to get a list of the methods the object has:

```
$ref = new ReflectionObject($myObj[0]);
print_r($ref->getMethods());
```